# Special price time dependent on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, price, eav, indexing, special-price

I am trying to make special price dependent to time on frontend. I have already managed to save the date with time on backend and inside data table `catalog_product_entity_datetime`thanks to this post [using time in special price from/to](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/using-time-in-special-price-from-to)

The problem is that the price is not changing after the time is reached. It only reads the date and so the prices only changes back to normal after 00:00:00 next day, as normal.

I could not find the controller responsible for this on "Mage_Catalog_block_Price"

Does anyone have an idea where is this controlled and how can I make the special price dependent on time?

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Gabriel

Comment: It probably has to do with Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default getDatePartSql(), how can I get full date and time from this, not only date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY. I could make special price to work absolutely depending on time.

Inside app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php

there is a function called isStoreDateInInterval.
Inside this function find:

```
if ($dateTo) {
            // fix date YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 to YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59
            $toTimeStamp += 86400;
        }
```

Comment out this lines and the price is going to update correctly depending on the time stored in database. I still do not know the downside if any date is stored without time, but it does not seem to be a problem.

To make it possible to store time in database refer to linked post.